# Eat MouseDown event after closing a WPF menu

Tags: wpf, menu, mouseevent

I'd like to implement a WPF `Menu` with the same behavior as the Office menus:

When you click on the `Menu`, it closes the menu but the clicked element does not receive a `MouseDown` event.

I thought of a couple of ways to do this but they are horribly complex.

Is there a relatively easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You could always handle the [PreviewMouseDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmousedown.aspx) event for your `Window`. In the handler, if your menu is open, close it and set [MouseButtonEventArgs.Handled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.handled.aspx) to `true`, preventing the event from being sent to whatever control was under the mouse.

Comment: This does not work because the menu is closed before the PreviewMouseDown event is fired